# mdadm does not find the superblock during the assemble operation

Tags: raid, mdadm

I had zero-filled partitions `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` which I put into Linux RAID:

```
# mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-disks=2 --metadata 1.0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.
#
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      487360 blocks super 1.0 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
#
```

Both `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` were part of another mirror before if this matters.
Now after I stopped the newly created `md0` mirror with `mdadm --stop --scan` and tried to re-assemble all the arrays with `mdadm --assemble --scan`, then the `/dev/md0` is no longer discovered while rest or the mirrors are:

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md3 : active raid1 sda4[2] sdb4[1]
      892150784 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/7 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md2 : active raid1 sda3[2] sdb3[1]
      29280256 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[2] sdb2[1]
      15617024 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
#
```

If I try to assemble the `md0` array using verbose output, then it says, that there is no superblock on `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1`:

```
# mdadm -vv --assemble /dev/md0
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/md/3
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/md/2
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/md/1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sde2
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sde1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sde
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sr1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd
mdadm: cannot open device /dev/sr0: No medium found
mdadm: /dev/sdb4 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: /dev/sdb3 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: /dev/sdb2 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb
mdadm: /dev/sda4 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: /dev/sda3 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: /dev/sda2 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop0
#
```

However, if I inspect the superblock data on RAID1 members, then it is present:

```
# mdadm --misc -E /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 5a0545c5:e5b8c31b:0982665c:0cdfe114
           Name : ubuntu:0  (local to host ubuntu)
  Creation Time : Wed Apr  7 14:21:25 2021
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 974816 (476.06 MiB 499.11 MB)
     Array Size : 487360 (476.02 MiB 499.06 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 974720 (476.02 MiB 499.06 MB)
   Super Offset : 974832 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=104 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 51c870bf:c75f1072:ff17ffcb:0d794b70

    Update Time : Wed Apr  7 14:21:27 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset -8 sectors
       Checksum : c908caac - correct
         Events : 17


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
#
# mdadm --misc -E /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 5a0545c5:e5b8c31b:0982665c:0cdfe114
           Name : ubuntu:0  (local to host ubuntu)
  Creation Time : Wed Apr  7 14:21:25 2021
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 974816 (476.06 MiB 499.11 MB)
     Array Size : 487360 (476.02 MiB 499.06 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 974720 (476.02 MiB 499.06 MB)
   Super Offset : 974832 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=104 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : e8517473:237cf164:8fb85c22:5ef79704

    Update Time : Wed Apr  7 14:21:27 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset -8 sectors
       Checksum : 5a978f80 - correct
         Events : 17


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
#
```

What might cause such behavior?

Comment: Do you have an /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf file that specifies /dev/md0 with a different metadata format?

Comment: To my surprise, I indeed had a `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` present. It was auto generated by `/usr/share/mdadm/mkconf` script. Sorry for not checking something that obvious. Could you please add your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf file specifies that array with a different metadata format, then mdadm will only look for that one and not find it.